# lambda expression how to express or?

Tags: c#

I want to use lambda expression to search status equals to 1 or 2.
My code is like following:

```
return database.Find<Patient>(p=>(p.Id==Id && p.status ==1)||(p.Id==Id && p.status==2));
```

I know it's not right, but you understand what I want to do from the above code.

I use c#

---

Update: sorry guys, I just realize that it is not the reason of syntax, it's the reason of the third party api I use to get data from db. Please close this question.

Comment: That should be valid...what's not working?

Comment: You have a 20 in the code and a 2 in the spec...

Comment: [_lambada expression_](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x1bkvn_kaoma-lambada-original-1989-version_music) ?!

Answer (score 6):

```
return database.Find<Patient>(p=>p.Id==Id && 
        (p.status ==1 || p.status==2));
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, it could be simplified a bit, but it should work as what you have is semantically equivalent to the simplified version below.

```
return database.Find(p => p.Id == Id && (p.Status == 1 || p.Status == 2));
```

One thing to note; you say you need to find the patient with a status of 1 or 2, yet your code says 1 or 20.  Did you copy that snippet directly (i.e., is this a simple typo problem?)

Answer (score 2):

I would probably reduce it down a little, but I think what you have right now should work.

```
return database.Find<Patient>(p => p.Id==Id && (p.status == 1 || p.status == 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you have written "20" instead of "2" ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that `database` in this code snippet refers to a valid DataContext. I would use `Where` instead of `Find`:

```
return database.Where(p=>(p.Id == Id && (p.status == 1 || p.status == 20));
```

Comment: If it wouldn't be a `List<T>` there wouldn't be a [`Find`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc.aspx) method. Although you might be right and OP just used a bad example to confuse us even more.